# How to use `@Observable` Macro within an Extension

Tags: swift, observable, ios17

I tend to add my view models within extensions of my views for namespacing-purposes, for example:

```
struct MyView: View {
  ...
}

extension MyView {
  final class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    ...
  }
}
```

However, restructuring `MyViewModel` to use the new `@Observable` macro causes all builds to fail - not even with a particular error message, just `Command SwiftCompile failed with a nonzero exit code`:

```
extension MyView {
  @Observable final class MyViewModel {
    ...
  }
}
```

I would certainly like to avoid having to *not* put my view models in extensions, but I also would love to be able to use this new macro. Does anyone know why this is causing an error or how to fix it?

Comment: You'll need to look at what the actual error is from the logs. "nonzero exit code" doesn't tell us anything. That said, it's likely crashing, and so a compiler bug. You'll have to open a report to bugs.swift.org so they can fix it.